# Grails Database Migration Plugin and GORM inheritance

Tags: grails, database-migration

We are migrating our application to Grails database-migration plugin and faced with problem with inheritance in GORM.

If child has less stricter rules then parent plugin generates changelog based on parent constraints.

Example:

```
class A {
    String foo

    static constraints = {
           foo (nullable: true)
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static constraints = {
           foo (nullable: false)
    }
}
```

Grails migration tries to add NOT NULL constraint to field foo.

As a workaround we created abstract parent class C with the weakest constraints but I don't like this solution.

Is there any elegant solution to handle this issue?

Comment: It's important to note the `dbm-gorm-diff` isn't meant to be taken as scripture. It's meant to save you a lot of time writing your own migrations. Every time one is generated it should be checked for accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Currently in our project dbm-gorm-diff generate around **40** irrelevant differences. So this problem is not only one. We definitely should move to this plugin because all significant migrations we handle manually with SQL queries. So I think we will use dbm-gorm-diff as a helper as you suggested. Thanks!